# Why are anonymous edits permitted?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, editing

Every so often, I get an edit request come up in the approval queue, which takes an answer with a link in, and replaces it with gibbering pseudo-sentences.

These edit suggestions always come from anonymous (therefore unregistered?) users. As questions and answers require registration, why don't we apply the same standards for suggesting edits? Especially as I have (so far) not seen a genuine edit from an anonymous user.

Comment: The main site throws in trick questions like that to see if you are paying attention.  If you miss a few times, it turns off your review access for a while.

Comment: Sounds like an answer more than a comment - they aren't allowed, and it' the system checking you're not a bot/repwhore.

Comment: Note that answering does not actually require registration (you need to provide an email address, but I'm pretty sure we don't verify it before your post goes live). Last I checked (this was on Stack Overflow, though, so take this with a grain of salt), a decent number of anonymous edits were getting accepted, so I wouldn't go as far as saying all edits from anon users are bad. If you feel this deserves more investigation, I'll try and get exact umbers for travel.SE. Just let me know.

Comment: It turns out that all of the anonymous edit I was rejecting were to this answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12787/finding-flights-to-cuba-with-a-flight-search-engine/12795#12795 . Now that it's been locked, no more regular fake edits.

Answer (score 4):

SE accepts contributions by anonymous users because the goal here is to create a database of quality questions and answers, regardless of who provides the content. If there's someone out there who might have a valid contribution to make to the sites, why force that person to register?

Now I agree with you that this mechanism inevitably attracts spam edits from geniuses who think that SE users are sound asleep whilst reviewing posts. However I trust in the reviewing system and, as your experience shows, it seems to work.