# Spammers are targetting my answer

Tags: support, spam

It seems spammers are targeting one of my answers. Basically, they are [submitting edit requests](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39615) that is just filler text, with links.

What can I do to remedy this? Should I just delete my answer?

I notice that [one of the other answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/12795/3956) to the same question has been locked, presumably for the same reason. There's a link to read more, but it doesn't point anywhere useful.

[image: Spam edits]

Comment: Continue rejecting the edit and report the user to community mods.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the other answer on the same Q was getting constant edit requests - it prompted me to make this meta thread - [Why are anonymous edits permitted?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/why-are-anonymous-edits-permitted) . Eventually I realized that all the edits were to the same answer, an flagged the answer to the moderators. - leading to the locking. I suggest you do the same.

The question remains though as to why this particular question attracts spammers, and beyond that anonymous spammers who want to remove links and replace with link-free gibberish.